# Time Complexity for the given algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, strings

Recently, I had to implement the following algorithm (similarly). Code in Kotlin:

```
fun solution(keyword: String, lyric: String): Boolean {
        val lyricWords = music.split(" ") 
        var index = 0
        for (word in lyricWords) {
          for (c in word) {
            if (c == keyword[index]) {
              index++
              break
            }
            if (index == word.size) return true
        }
        return false
 }
```

My intuition to the runtime analysis, given `n` to be the length of lyric and `m` the length of keyword:

1. O(n) for the `split` operation, since it should scan the entire string looking for spaces.
2. Roughly O(n) for the second for-loop, since it would iterate through all the characters for every word in the worst case.
3. O(m) for the internal for-loop over all characters in keyword.
4. Overall, should that take under O(n+m)?

What would be the time complexity for the above function?

Comment: Assuming a reasonable implementation of `split()`, constant-time access to each element the collection `lyricWords`, and constant-time access the $i$-th character in a string, the time complexity would be $O(n)$. Notice that if $m = \omega(n)$ you still do only $O(n)$ iterations of the inner loop. This is tight, in the sense that there are some inputs for which the time spent is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: 1. Coding questions are off-topic here, and analyzing the running time of a chunk of code generally requires information that is beyond the scope of this site (e.g., the running time of various programming language primitives, like `in`).  Not everyone here knows Kotlin, and the details of Kotlin are off-topic here.  We'd prefer that you share your code as concise pseudocode. 2. What attempts have you made?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755 for the general approach.

Answer (score 1):

For loop inside For loop indicates multiplication of time complexity parts.

For loop following for loop indicates addition of time complexity parts.

So I'd expect: $O(mn)$

That is to say. You doing $O(m)$, $n$ number of times. Thus $O(mn)$.